# High Side Driver Array Against ULN2804 For Motor loads Such As UDN2981, TD62783, TPIC6B595

Tags: pnp

Building a circuit to drive a few DC motors with UNO, 74HC595 and ULN2804. I had no issues with coding, connections and timings.

Then I started searching for high side driver arrays to control polarity of motors individually. I can't go for an H-Bridge, as the result will be bulky and expensive. Upon searching the web since 3 days, I found a few solutions like UDN2981, UDN2987, TPIC6B595, TD62783 and similar ICs and individual transistors like BC327 etc.
But they're falling behind the requirement Of 500mA of continues output current for at least 100ms when all channels are active.

Few of the above are giving 500mA output, but At one active channel or at 10% duty cycle.

Please help me to find the one, or suggest the best way to use the above.

Comment: Can you use English capitalisation of first word in sentence, proper nouns and initialisations only? This is very difficult to read. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: ULN2804 sinks 500mA at 50V per channel, less when multiple channels are driven. UDN2981 sources 500mA at 50V per channel, less when multiple channels are driven. Can you explain why one is suitable, and the other not?

Comment: Thanks For The Response Mr.Neil_UK. Theoretically right, But I got Confused When I Was Able to Draw  >1 Amp from Single Channel Of ULN2804 And Not From UDN2981.

Comment: Can You Give Some Clarification On UDN2981 And TD62783. As UDN2981 Becoming Obsolete.

Comment: It's not advisable to draw more current from an IC than is in its specification. The fact that you can do it now doesn't mean that you will be able to keep on doing it. Design to specification, not to sample.

Comment: Please Confirm,  CAN I USE ULN2804 & UDB2981 IN COMBINATION to drive 12V motors.

Comment: Was the TD62783 is same as UDN2981 ??